# Register and unregister services in Dryioc

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

I am creating application in Xamarin.Forms using Prism.Forms. It works quite well using Unity IOC. Because Unity lacks of some features I want to move to Dryioc.

Because components (for example pages) of application changes at runtime so I need to register and unregister this components dynamically. How to do it in Dryioc? It seems possible using Container.OpenScope() but this approach creates new container which can not be used by Prism. Prism creates and uses single container for whole application lifetime. Am I right?

So is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems possible using Container.OpenScope()

No, DryIoc does not separate registrations between scopes, **they always go to the root container**.

You may re-register a new service by passing `IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace` parameter. For this to work, you need also modify both the old and the new registration to use `Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true)`. Here is the [reason why](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/UnregisterAndResolutionCache#markdown-header-make-injected-dependency-re-wireable-by-registering-it-asresolutioncall).

Intial setup:

```
container.Register<MyServiceUser>();
container.Register<IService, MyService>(
    setup: Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true));
```

Replacing `IService`:

```
container.Register<IService, MyReplacementService>(
    ifAlreadyRegistered: IfAlreadyRegistered.Replace,
    setup: Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true));
```

Comment: Thanks! When using OpenScope() is it possible to resolve also from root container? From my tests seems it is not possible. Also is it possible to delegate resolution to my own factory if container cannot resolve?

Comment: "When using OpenScope() is it possible to resolve also from root container?"
yes, it is possible - need to see what's not working for you.

"Also is it possible to delegate resolution to my own factory if container cannot resolve?" Yes, e.g. `container = container.With(rules => rules.WithUnknownServiceResolvers(req => 
    req.ServiceType != typeof(MyType) ? null : new DelegateFactory(_ => new MyType())));`

Comment: *var main = new Container();
main.Register<IFoo, Foo1>(reuse: Reuse.Scoped);
using (var child = main.OpenScope())
{
    var childFoo = child.Resolve<IFoo>();
    var mainFoo = main.Resolve<IFoo>();
    Assert.AreEqual(childFoo, mainFoo);
}*
throws: No current scope available.
Thanks for WithUnknownServiceResolvers, it works. I can't find information about it in documentation. Also nothing about WithDynamicRegistrations which seems also good solution.

Comment: Here some: https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/RulesAndDefaultConventions#markdown-header-unknownserviceresolvers

Comment: The bitbucket links are dead. Here is the new one https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/ReuseAndScopes.md#scopecontext